# Drawing particles with CPU instead of GPU (XNA)

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I'm trying out modifications to the following particle system.
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/particle_3d

I have a function such that when I press Space, all the particles have their positions and velocities set to 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i < particles.GetLength(0); i++)  
{  
    particles[i].Position = Vector3.Zero;      
    particles[i].Velocity = Vector3.Zero;  
}
```

However, when I press space, the particles are still moving. If I go to FireParticleSystem.cs I can turn settings.Gravity to 0 and the particles stop moving, but the particles are still not being shifted to (0,0,0).

As I understand it, the problem lies in the fact that the GPU is processing all the particle positions, and it's calculating where the particles should be based on their initial position, their initial velocity and multiplying by their age. Therefore, all I've been able to do is change the initial position and velocity of particles, but I'm unable to do it on the fly since the GPU is handling everything.

I want the CPU to calculate the positions of the particles individually. This is because I will be later implementing some sort of wind to push the particles around. How do I stop the GPU from taking over? I think it's something to do with VertexBuffers and the draw function, but I don't know how to modify it to make it work.

Comment: You might also try gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

The sample you downloaded is not capable of doing what you ask. You are correct in your diagnosis of the problem: the particle system is entirely maintained by the GPU, and so your changes to the position and velocity only change the start values, not the actual real-time particle values. To make a particle system that is changeable by the CPU, you need to make a particle engine class and do it yourself. There are many other samples out there that do this.

Riemers XNA tutorials are very useful. Try out this link:
http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Particle_engine.php

It teaches you how to make a 2D particle system. This can be easily converted into 3D.
Or, if you want to just download an existing engine, try the Mercury particle engine: 
http://mpe.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple ... all you have to do is do the position/velocity calculations on the CPU rather than offloading them to a shader. I of course can't see your code, so I can't really offer any more specific guidance ... but whether you animate your particles with a physics engine like FarSeer, or just do the basic equation of motion yourself. It'll happen on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [DPSF (Dynamic Particle System Framework)](http://www.xnaparticles.com/) for this. It does the calculations on the CPU, is fully customizable and very flexible, has great help docs and tutorials, and it even provides the full source code for the FireParticleSystem from the Particle3D sample that you are using. You should be able to have the particle system integrated into your game and accomplishing what you want within a matter of minutes.